# GRUB2: /boot as BTRFS subvolume

Tags: linux, boot, grub, btrfs

Aside from `/boot`, all my partitions (including root, `/`) are BTRFS subvolumes. I'm switching to BTRFS RAID1, and for the sake of integrity, want to include `/boot` within the BTRFS partition. Preferably as a separate subvolume (quota support) but possible as part of the root subvolume. I'm using the latest fedora, 22, which [means](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/):

- grub2 2.02-0.16.fc22
- btrfs-progs 4.0-1.fc22
- kernel 4.0.4-303.fc22

**Is this possible (yes/no)? Please provide information on any BTRFS+GRUB specific setup.** I mean, creating a new subvolume and copying data is relatively straightforward, but getting the whole contraption to actually *boot* is another problem entirely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Myself successfully moved /boot into the BTRFS system as a subvolume. No special consideration necessary - just don't forget to reinstall grub and rebuild the initramfs.

*edit:*

Will require running `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` after every upgrade involving a kernel (linux, memtest, etc) or during/after a fedora upgrade (fedup) as `grubby` does not support updating `grub.cfg` on btrfs subvolumes. There is a patch available [[#864198 - see attachments](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=864198)] which hasn't been integrated because it's a hack. With kernel-install and BootLoaderSpec, grubby seems to be nearing end-of-life, so I don't find it objectionable.

*TLDR:*

Requires updating `grub.cfg` manually every post-kernel upgrade, which is painless unless you've directly edited it.

Comment: Can you please provide detailed instructions on how you did this? It will be useful for many.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad idea since you wont be able to use efistub and boot the kernel directly without using grub.

If you want integrity, you can use md raid1 for /boot